# Cannot ping my domain-joined server - Can only ping domain controller - host unreachable

Tags: domain-controller, ping

I have a HyperV Server hosting a Domain Controller VM (192.168.1.50) and another VM (192.168.1.51) joined to this domain.

I have:

- domain controller as DNS server
- forward lookup zone for the domain with host record for 192.168.1.50 and 192.168.1.51
- Windows client has primary DNS server set to 192.168.1.50 and secondary to my ISP

I can ping 192.168.1.50 (domain controller) successfully but cannot ping 192.168.1.51 (domain-joined VM)

When pinging from Windows client:

```
ping 192.168.1.51
 Reply from 192.168.1.129 : Destination host unreachable
```

When pinging from Domain Controller:

```
ping 192.168.1.51   
 Reply from 192.168.1.50 : Destination host unreachable
```

I have 2 virtual network adapters one PRIVATE for intranet (set to static IP 192.168.1.51) and one PUBLIC for internet with a dynamic IP.

I noticed the the PUBLIC one inherited the "mydomain.com" domain subtitle after joining the domain... I don't know what this meant but it seemed more intuitive to me to switch THIS ONE to have the static IP. After I configured that I still could not ping but now I get:

```
ping 192.168.1.51
 Request timed out
```

What seems to be the issue, I'm relatively new to networking.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most likely explanation is that you have the Windows firewall enabled on 192.168.1.51

Try disabling it completely, and see if that allows you to ping that VM.